# sporadic NullPointerException despite the fact, that the Object is not null

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, android-listfragment

Im getting a sporadic (1 out of ~30 times) NullPointerException in this line of Code. and I have no Idea where it comes from and how to prevent it.

```
public void close() {
    if (mDb!=null)
        mDb.close();
}
```

mDb is a SQliteDatabase Object and the Close function is implemented into a Helper class.

What I am doing: I want to handle a complex query in that SQliteDatabase with an AsyncTask.
Here is the code of the AsyncTask:

```
private class processCursorTask extends AsyncTask<Integer[], Void, Dataset[]> {
    private DbHelper mDb;

    processCursorTask(DbHelper db) {
        super();
        mDb=db;
    }

    @Override
    protected Dataset[] doInBackground(Integer... args) {
        Dataset[] res=mDb.getCursorFiltered(args);
        mDb.close();
        return res;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Dataset[] result) {
        setListView(result);
    }
}
```

And I am creating this AsyncTask here (from a ListFragment):

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    new processCursorTask(new DbHelper(this.getActivity()), mBaseDivision, mBaseValue, mSortOrder, mSortDir).execute();
}
```

> 03-26 00:44:20.489: E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(6442): sqlite3_close(0x3b2278)
>   failed: 27      03-26 00:44:20.520: W/dalvikvm(6442): threadid=12:
>   thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a691f8)        03-26
>   00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
>   03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()           03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):
>     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
>   03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>   03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>   03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>   03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>   03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
>   03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)           03-26 00:44:20.520:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(6442): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.closeDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1156)
>   03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.close(SQLiteDatabase.java:1105)
>   03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):   at
>   de.kialelem.trainer.DbHelper.close(DbHelper.java:676)        03-26
>   00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):     at
>   de.kialelem.trainer.ViewContentDatabaseListFragment$processCursorTask.doInBackground(ViewContentDatabaseListFragment.java:48)
>   03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):   at
>   de.kialelem.trainer.ViewContentDatabaseListFragment$processCursorTask.doInBackground(ViewContentDatabaseListFragment.java:1)
>   03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)            03-26
>   00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   03-26 00:44:20.520: E/AndroidRuntime(6442):   ... 5 more

Comment: Could it be due to concurrent access to the `mDb` instance without proper synchronization?

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to make your mDb volatile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:
The Problem was that the DbHelper Object was created on the UI thread but closed in the asyncTask worker thread.
After I moved the .close() into the onPostExecute() method the exception disappeared.

```
private class processCursorTask extends AsyncTask<Integer[], Void, Dataset[]> {
private DbHelper mDb;

processCursorTask(DbHelper db) {
    super();
    mDb=db;
}

@Override
protected Dataset[] doInBackground(Integer... args) {
    Dataset[] res=mDb.getCursorFiltered(args);
    return res;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Dataset[] result) {
    mDb.close();
    setListView(result);
}
}
```

Comment: I am running into it, I will try your solution

Comment: I am running into it, I will try your solution. How are you sure it works? I had the object created on pre-execute, db connection opened and closed in thread do in background and  I got crash

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what class your `close()` method above belongs to. In any event, you are calling `mDb.close()` twice: once in `close()` and once in `doInBackground()`.

The exception is happening inside `SQLiteDatabase.closeDatabase()`, so it's *not* caused by your `mDb` being `null`.

As a general rule, don't bother closing the database. Open it once on app startup, and reuse the same connection throughout your app. You get no benefit from closing it, since SQLite's transactional nature ensures all writes are committed to storage at the earliest opportunity anyway.

**EDIT**: OK, I can see now that the `mDb` in each case is different. In any event, take my advice about not closing the DB, and the problem will go away.

Comment: I had that before, but the listFragment where the code above is from, is used inside a FragmentPager. When I used one and the same Database Object it was throwing Exceptions, when to many Fragments where used. This is my try to work around. And what I dont get about it, how come, that this nullPointerException is only thrown sporadic. And the database Object is only created for the AsyncTask. This means no other code is execute except the query method (which is actually not more than a rawQuery followed by a loop to convert the data into an Array).